# Backend receives null for body from axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios

I have the below request handler.

```
const axios = require('axios');

function parseJSON(response) {
  if (response.status === 204 || response.status === 205) {
    return null;
  }
  return response.data;
}

async function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }
  // we should never get here
  throw new Error('unknown');
}

const request = (url, options) => {
  const headers = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };
  const newOptions = {
    ...options,
    mode: 'cors',
    headers
  };
  console.log('request options:', newOptions);

  return axios(url, newOptions)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .catch((err) => {
      err.message = err.response?.data?.message;
      err.status = err.response?.status;
      throw err;
    });
};

export default request;
```

I have used more or less the same code in a bunch of projects. It has always worked fine. Now, I am trying to use it with a new ReactJS app. The `GET` call is working fine. However, when I am attempting to post, the body on the server side is empty. I have tried the same POST with `postman` and it is working fine. The server is OK.

The client data looks fine as well. My console.log() prints the below.

```
request options: {method: 'POST', body: '{"business_type":"C-CORP","incorporated_state":"AK…_rate":"5","loan_term_months":"5","coupon_id":1}', mode: 'cors', headers: {Content-Type: 'application/json'}}
```

The successful postman/curl request looks the same:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:5000/user/deal/new' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "coupon_id": 1,
    "business_type": "LLC",
    "incorporated_state": "NC",
    ...
    "account_id": 1
}
```

Yet, when I am printing the request on the server's end, the body is `null`.

```
"Cannot destructure property 'coupon_id' of 'req.body' as it is null."
```

Searched for similar issues on Google, and most people had wrong HTTP headers, but mine look fine, to me. Ideas?

Comment: Curl sends GET request, but you send POST by axios. Also can you show your node.js server?

Comment: Are you sure you need `mode: 'cors'`? If yes, are you sure you're looking at the body of the `POST` request not at the (non-existent) body of the preflight `OPTIONS` request?

Comment: @Bergi thank you for considering my question! I have tried with `no-cors` as well. No difference. Further, I do believe that my server is configured for `CORS`, and I am not looking at `OPTIONS` request, either unfortunately. I have not tried browser `fetch`, yet. Probably, makes sense as the next step.

Comment: fetch is working fine, no errors. what is that all about?